# Removing "Save Password" and "Restore Pages" popups

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have Excel VBA code that uses Selenium Basic ChromeDriver to login and navigate a website.

I'm trying to make it so that Chrome's popup prompts in the right corner asking either to "Save password" or "Restore Pages" don't appear.

Save password
[image]

Restore pages
[image]

My attempt.

```vb
Sub ChromeDriverTest()
    Dim bot2 As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Set bot2 = New ChromeDriver
    bot2.SetCapability "goog:chromeOptions", "{""excludeSwitches"": [""enable-automation""], ""args"":[""--start-maximized"",""--hide-scrollbars"", ""user-data-dir=C:\\ChromeTest"",""--disable-notifications"",""--no-sandbox"",""--no-first-run"",""--no-service-autorun"",""--password-store=basic""]}"
    bot2.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2
    bot2.SetPreference "credentials_enable_service", False
    bot2.SetPreference "profile.password_manager_enabled", False
    bot2.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 2000
```

I still get the "Save Password" prompt.
The "Restore pages?" prompt continues to happen after cases where ChromeDriver is stopped suddenly in the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the offer to restore pages, I don't know how to make it appear so I can't help with that.

Regarding the offer to save the password: when I tried your code the offer did appear but when I used only this line:

```
bot2.SetPreference "credentials_enable_service", False
```

The offer stopped appearing

Also, note that you must set preferences **before** calling the `start` method